# get the selected file from the input file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to put the selected file from the input file to the newly created 'formData' on form submit, below is what I have tried.

first I have the form

```
<form action="/upload.php">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <input type="text" name="full_name">
    </fieldset>
    <button>SEND</button>
</form>
```

and then the script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var dis = $(this),fdata = new FormData();
        fdata.append('file',dis.find('input[type="file"]').files[0]);
        fdata.append('full_name',dis.find('input[name="full_name"]').val());
    });
});
```

but it gives me this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Any help, ideas please?

Comment: fdata.append('file',dis.find('input[type="file"]')[0].files[0]);

Comment: Are you trying to upload file using ajax or just want to show the selected image on page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `dis.find('input[type="file"]')` returns jQuery object and they don't have `files` property thus you are getting the error, You need to get the underlying DOM element then access the property. So use

```
dis.find('input[type="file"]')[0].files[0]
```

instead of

```
dis.find('input[type="file"]').files[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

FormData accepts as input the form element

Try the following

```
fdata = new FormData($(this)[0]);
```

remove the append

Comment: Why not simple `new FormData(this)`?